# cocos2d: sprite offset

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I need to change offset of some of my sprites. I'm implementing it like this:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"Islands.plist"];
```

I know, I can set offset in the Islands.plist file, but I need to track on difference between original offset and modified one. How can I set frame's offset programmaticaly? Can I do this once and for all?

Comment: maybe I don't understand, what exactly you wanna do, but you can create CCSprite object with one of your spriteFrames and set new position to it. please, add some comments to clear what do you want to do =)

Comment: No. I'm using a box2d, so my sprites are missing phisical boby.

Comment: hmmm... still think, that we have a little misunderstanding =) usually i create a class of some inworld object, it has physical body and an instance of CCSprite(or CCNode, CCLabelTTF, etc.) to represent it on the screen of device. so it a bit strange to see smth like your previous comment.